# WebView:didFailLoadWithError not called after upgrade to iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

One of my apps is still using the UIWebView, and it's been fine all these years.  However, since upgrading to iOS 11.3, the delegate method WebView:didFailLoadWithError is not getting called in the same situation that is was called with previous versions of iOS.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Hey, did you got the solution for this?. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I am also facing the issue. Any leads for workarounds